# Updating files inside an existing WAR file

Tags: ant

I am trying to update files inside an existing WAR file using the ANT WAR task.
I need to replace a set of xml files in a folder in WAR with new ones from my HDD.

```
<war destfile="myApp.war" update="true" >
    <zipfileset dir="<PathToStubsFolderOnHDD>" includes="**/*.xml" prefix="<PathToStubsFolderInWAR>"/>
</war>
```

This works fine if the original WAR does not have xmls with same name. However if the original WAR contains xmls with same name; WAR task does not update them with files from HDD.

The ANT WAR task documentation reads:

> update | indicates whether to update or overwrite the destination file if it already exists. Default is "false".
>   duplicate | behavior when a duplicate file is found. Valid values are "add", "preserve", and "fail". The default value is "add".

if i use update="false"; all other files in the original WAR are deleted and only the new xmls stored.

using duplicate="add" didnot have any effect either.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems that with `update=true` option, the war file is newer than the files that you want to update. [Someone](http://markmail.org/message/qpzdtz2lenasbv7l) suggest to apply the `touch` task with '0' to workaround the problem.

> The zip task checks only if the source files you whish to add to an existing zip are more recent than the zip. A workaround would be to `<touch millis="0" />` the zip file before adding.

Or you could do the [reverse stuff](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200207.mbox/%3C003d01c22ff5$5a093100$0200a8c0@octovma%3E):

> Performing a `touch` before the `war` task on XML file(s) makes it
>   work.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks Aito!

Here is the complete ANT script:

```
<target name = "UpdateWARWithStubs"
    description="Updates WAR file with files from Stub folder">

    <!-- Use touch to set modification time of all stubs to current time. This will force war task to update stub files inside the war -->
    <tstamp> <format property="touch.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"/>  </tstamp>
    <touch datetime="${touch.time}">
        <fileset dir="${path.to.stubs.on.hdd}" />
    </touch>

    <war destfile="myApp.war" update="true">
        <zipfileset dir="${path.to.stubs.on.hdd}"  prefix="${path.to.stubs.in.war}"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

Comment: Where is the war path to the war file to be updated defined in the above example?

Comment: You could just hardcode the path as destfile="path/for/war/myApp.war" or better read the value from properties ${path.for.war}/${file.name.war}

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. `<war destfile="myApp.war" update="true">
        <zipfileset dir="${path.to.stubs.on.hdd}"  prefix="${path.to.stubs.in.war}"/>`
    </war>

Comment: stack overflow wouldnt let me edit previous comment... I am trying to do something similar. `<war destfile="myApp.war" update="true" needxmlfile="false"> <zipfileset dir="C:\" includes="extrafile.txt" prefix=""/></war>` My extra file is in the war but WEB-INF is gone. I tried it without needxmlfile but build failed. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to replace existing files in zip(.war) file. Initial state is I have build.xml to compile and package mywebapp.war for Tomcat6 server. Minor configuration changes within war file are required for Tomcat7 server.

- project subfolders web and webT7 are CVS controlled folders, I don't want to touch  timestamps for no reason. The following trick does the job.
- compile and create web/WEB-INF/lib/mywebapp.jar file as usual
- target "war" creates tomcat6 archive from web folder
- have few specific files in webT7 subfolder such as META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/web.xml ones I have to modify a bit for each tomcat version.
- create a copy of mywebapp.war.zip file
- copy files from webT7 subfolder to a new build temp folder, do not use preservelastmodified attribute !!! This gives a new timestamp for each files, so its touches without separate touch command.
- failsafe touch new zip to put past timestamp, this makes sure zip update works properly.
- use zip task to update mywebapp.war_T7.zip content, it should replace existing files because we copied them without preserving original timestamps.

Reason I copy webT7 content to a temp build folder is content management systems. I don't want to change timestamps of the original repository files for no reason. Everything else compile,jar,war targets are always same no matter what Tomcat target I use.

Zip update="true" attribute as was said earlier do not replace files, it updates only if zip had older file than the one we give. This may introduce problems if I have web/config.jsp(2013-01-21 14:01:01) and webT7/config.jsp(2012-12-21 15:02:03) files. File was not replaced.

**Snippet from build.xml file**

```
<target name="war" depends="compile,jar" description="Create a .war file">
    <delete file="${name}.war.zip" />
    <zip destfile="${name}.war.zip"
        basedir="./web/"
        excludes="
            **/CVS*
            "
    />
</target>

<target name="warT7" depends="war" description="Create a .war file for Tomcat7">
    <delete dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />

    <delete file="${name}.war_T7.zip" />
    <copy file="${name}.war.zip" 
      tofile="${name}.war_T7.zip" overwrite="true" preservelastmodified="true"
    />      

    <copy todir="${build}" overwrite="true">
      <fileset dir="./webT7" />
    </copy>

    <touch datetime="01/31/1981 01:00:00 AM" file="${name}.war_T7.zip" />
    <zip destfile="${name}.war_T7.zip" update="true">
      <zipfileset dir="${build}"  prefix="" />
    </zip>
    <delete dir="${build}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to explode the war to a temporary directory, make your changes and then rebuild the war. Not nice, admittedly.

Answer (score 0):

Neither touch option worked for me. The original war file being created by a maven artifact from within the ant script might have something to do with this. Ended up repackaging the war file into a temp file and overwriting the original war file like this:

```
<target name="update-properties">
    <war destfile="target/${war.name}temp" needxmlfile='false'>
        <zipfileset src="target/${war.name}" includes="**/*" 
                      excludes="${path.to.properties.in.war}" />
        <zipfileset file="${path.to.new.properties}"  
                      fullpath="${path.to.properties.in.war}" />
    </war>
    <move file="target/${local.war.name}temp" tofile="target/${local.war.name}"/>
    <delete file="target/${local.war.name}temp"/>
</target>
```

where `${path.to.properties.in.war`} can be something like `"WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/database.properties"`