# Replace a file in zip using Ant despite of timestamp

Tags: ant

I want to replace 1-2 files in a huge archive using zip task (or any other ANT task that can do this). I know passing `update=true` parameter can do it but it is only if new file has grater timestamp than old file. I want to make sure that the file gets replaced even though it has old timestamp as compared to the file in existing archive.

I have gone through several posts where they suggest **unzip-replace-rezip** thing. However I want to **avoid this if possible** because my archive is huge (in GBs). Is there any other way which has minimum performance impact?

Other way I found was using `zipfileset` task as follows:

```
<zip destfile="tmp.jar"> 
      <zipfileset src="src.jar"> 
           <exclude name="abc.class" />  
      </zipfileset> 
      <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/myclasses" includes="abc.class" />
</zip> 
<move file="tmp.jar" tofile="src.jar" />
```

Does this task do the same as **unzip-delete-add-rezip** for entire archive? Or is it more efficient in terms of time?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210041/updating-files-inside-an-existing-war-file. It talks about war, but should be useful to you.

Comment: Yeah I have seen it. But touching existing file with current timestamp will not always be reliable in my case because my archive may contain some future dated files (I know this is weird but while packaging the archive we used to do touch with +24 hrs offset to ensure file will be replaced for sure in multiple timezones. This is legacy code in our product. We can remove it as much as possible but still there is a chance to have a future dated file in archive.